# Need a line to work in native JQuery to go to ANCHOR

Tags: javascript, wordpress, click, anchor

I have a site with wordpress, slider revolution and bridge theme.

I am setting up a contact button on slider revolution that have to go to an anchor on the same window.

When i setup the anchor on Bridge theme it set up like this data-`q_id="#nos-eligen"`

```
<div data-q_id="#nos-eligen" class="vc_row wpb_row section vc_row-fluid  vc_custom_1563900392108 grid_section" style=" text-align:center;">
```

I try this line

```
var elmnt = document.getElementById("nos-eligen");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

but it doesnt work because `id="nos-eligen"` is not defined.

I need a line that works with `data-q_id` tag

Does anyone know how to do it?
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `id`, select by (the data-property) `data-q_id` attribute:

```
var elmnt = document.querySelector("[data-q_id=#nos-eligen]");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

(Doesn't require jQuery)

Comment: @JoseLuisLujan Did this answer help you?

Comment: It doesn't 
response `VM144:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[data-q_id=#nos-eligen]' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:22`

Comment: @JoseLuisLujan What happens if you put the id in quotes, i.e., `[data-q_id='#nos-eligen']`